# Will using the 'restrict' keyword in ARM improve my code?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, cortex-m

I was doing some research and came across [this article](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html) which describes the `restrict` keyword quite well and I think I have a decent grasp of its valid usage as a result. To quote the article's quote of the definition of `restrict`:

> A new feature of C99: The restrict type qualifier allows programs to be written so that translators can produce significantly faster executables. [...] Anyone for whom this is not a concern can safely ignore this feature of the language.
>   -- From Rationale for International Standard - Programming Languages - C [std.dkuug.dk] (6.7.3.1 Formal definition of restrict)

In my case this happens to be true; I'm writing embedded code which could benefit for higher performance compiled code and I am not comfortable enough with assembly to utilize it for help. So I am considering utilizing `restrict` in appropriate places. Specifically, I have several functions which loop and take pointer arguments of the same type, so it seems like my code could benefit from this on the surface.

However, the article states:

> You should expect code where all aliasing information is declared with the restrict keyword to almost always perform significantly better, and never worse, than with unrestricted pointers. This is especially true on superscalar RISC, or RISC-like architectures with large register files, like the PowerPC or MIPS R4000.

I am working with an ARM Cortex-M4 with the GCC toolchain. I don't have enough understanding of the various processor architectures to compare the meaning of `large register files` to my use case, but given the example processors given and a quick Google search, I am pretty sure I don't constitute that list, though perhaps the application class ARM processors would be.

So with all this in mind, would I see a benefit beyond micro-optimization? I fully expect to profile it one way or the other, but I was wondering about the qualitative effects of `restrict` in the context of ARM Cortex-M4/GCC, and specifically, if its pipeline could make use of the changes or if there is some other factor that will prevent a major benefit, such as not being able to schedule memory access.

Comment: Without looking assembly you can't really tell if there's any advantage (optimization) of using `restrict`. But `restrict` is defined such that the code will behave as if the `restrict` is not present at all in case the target architecture couldn't perform any optimizations (any incorrect use of `restrict` could lead to incorrect code generated, of course).

Comment: This is a bit too vague and/or like a "what do you think?"-type question, which is a bad fit for this forum. My suggestion would be to just add `restrict` to a function or two, and compare the generated code before and after. Profiling is more work, reading code just to see "something happened" can be enough.

Comment: @unwind, with respect, I don't feel that it is too broad, though I would agree with perhaps migrating it to the programmer exchange. Perhaps I could reword the question but I am asking specifically about the effects of restrict in the ARM Cortex processor and how much its pipeline could benefit from its use.

Comment: Understanding the benefits of `restrict` is deeply intertwined with the understanding of strict aliasing. I'd suggest reading up on some of the optimizations (and horror stories) of strict aliasing. Then understanding that `restrict` is basically instructing the compiler to apply strict aliasing where it normally would not be able to!. The main benefits of strict aliasing would be in reordering of operations, though

Comment: @mnunberg Thanks, I'll do some reading on the matter. My root question about the architecture still stands though. I only even question it because of the articles references to superscalar CPUs.

Comment: There is nothing specific to your ARM platform that would make restrict more or less useful than usual, though better vectorization is one of the common benefits on platforms that have a vector unit.

Comment: I believe that `restrict` can be beneficial on almost all architectures as the compiler may cache values in registers and assume that a *restricted pointer* that was modified in the mean time has not updated a *register cached* value.  Gcc uses a SSA form that can include memory operands. *This is especially true on superscalar RISC* **does not** parse to *it is not true on non-superscaler*. Given your code is correct, `restrict` will be equal or better.  That said, some people are turn-off by over-use.  Profile and consider using `restrict` if you find a  bottleneck.

Comment: @MarkNunberg: Most of the horror stories I've read involve cases where storage needs to be reused or reinterpreted as different types, the programmer knows there's aliasing involved, and the programmer wants the compiler to know that.  By contrast, `restrict` is for cases where the programmer knows that no aliasing is necessary.  Totally different.

Answer (score 0):

`Restrict` keyword allows compiler to remove dependencies between some memory operations in program. This opens opportunities to large number of optimizations e.g. tighter instruction schedules (which in turn enables higher benefits from loop unrolling), autovectorization or combining multiple scalar loads/stores to vectorized variants (`ldm`/`stm` in case of ARM).

Upper class, out-of-order architectures (e.g. Cortex-A in ARM's case) try very hard (and spend a lot of power) to perform these optimizations at runtime, by dynamically analyzing and reordering the instruction stream (even there `restrict` may enable higher-level optimizations like autovectorization). Lower-end, embedded cores like M4 lack such capabilities and so `restrict` annotations are absolutely crucial for performance there.

As other commenters have noted, semantics of `restrict` is not exactly trivial so I suggest to utilize it only in hot loops.